# HTML in Email Signature not displaying properly

Tags: apex, email, html, service-cloud-console

I wrote out the email signature in HTML to meet our company's branding. Inside of a .html file the code renders really nicely. As soon as I put this into the my email signature inside of Salesforce, it blows up. The code does not render properly. Are there certain HTML standards that I am not following for salesforce?

```
    <div style="background-color:white">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                    <br>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr style="display: block;">
                            <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#333333">
                                    Matthew M
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:block;line-height: 2.0;">
                            <td style="font-size:9.0pt;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#b4b4b4;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:.75pt">
                                    CUSTOMER SUCCESS DIRECTOR
                             </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:block;">
                                    <td>
                                            <span style="padding-right: 30px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;">O</span> <span style="color:#333333">+517 345 803 675 </span></span> <span style="font-weight: bold;">M</span> <span style="color:#333333">+517 XXX XXX XXX</span>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display: block;">
                                    <td>
                                            <span style="padding-right: 30px;"><span style="font-weight: bold;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;">E</span> <span style="color:#333333"><a href:"mailto:matthew@gmail.com">Matthew@gmail.com</a></span></span> 
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="display:block;margin-top:20px;">
                                    <td>
                                            <img src="OurLogo">
                                    </td>
                            </tr>

                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that might cause problems is the `<br/>`. There should not be a line break outside of a cell inside a table. Everything else should probably be okay.